# Digest Authentication not working in JMeter

Tags: http, jmeter, performance-testing

I wanted to have digest authentication Authorization header added in very http request and hence added HTTP Authorization Manager under thread group. I added URL,username, password, domain, realm (both to same name) and selected BASIC_DIGEST as the option (I wanted only digest authentication).

I also uncommented http.authentication.preemptive$Boolean=true in httpclient.parameters and uncommented httpclient.parameters.file=C:\apache-jmeter-2.12\apache-jmeter2.12\bin\httpclient.parameters in jmeter.properties file.

After done, I closed my jmeter and started it again. When I gave a run and did a wireshark capture, I figured out that GET was sent with NO Authorization header, and server sends a 401 response and jmeter closes socket and fails the case.

I am not sure what I have done wrong. Awaiting for your comments.

JMeter Logs:
2014/11/20 13:19:35 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-1 
2014/11/20 13:19:35 INFO  - org.apache.commons.httpclient.auth.AuthChallengeProcessor: digest authentication scheme selected 
2014/11/20 13:19:35 INFO  - org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector: No credentials available for DIGEST 'users@perf.tb.com'@192.168.100.30:80

Answer (score 1):

1. Realm should not be required for digest authentication, domain is quite enough
2. Make sure that you're using either HttpClient3.1 or HttpClient4 implementation
3. See [Windows Authentication with Apache JMeter](http://blazemeter.com/blog/windows-authentication-apache-jmeter) guide for details on how to configure HTTP Authorization Manager for digest and kerberos authentication types